# value is not getting passed from view to controller action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi am new to rails and am not finding the solution for this particular problem, please help.

The value is not getting passed from view to controller action.

This is my view.

```
         <%= form_tag({action: :update_table_one}, multipart: true, method: :post)  do%> 

                <label class=" control-label">Tables :</label>
                <%= select_tag 'val', options_for_select(@v.each{ |value| [ value ] }) %> <br> 

                <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default") do %>
                 Submit
                <% end %>  

          <% end %>
```

This is my controller action

```
def update_table_one 

    require 'pg'

    value = params[:val] 

    begin

          con = PG.connect :dbname => 'abc', :user => 'Mrx',
          :password => 'xyz'

          con.exec "DELETE FROM #{value}"  

      rescue PG::Error => e

          puts e.message 

      ensure

          con.close if con

    end            

end
```

This is my console

```
Started GET "/page/update_table?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=pKvsDq8Lj5fI8Gw%2BIa%2BLMnsKIM%2FfElmrCHsQHmmK6xnqZrLr3ei4gVhCipEEu9ntO3fFZ9ZwncLwx0X%2Bdcnrjg%3D%3D&val=+tmp_kapow_test&button=" for ::1 at 2017-03-05 22:41:49 +0530
Processing by PageController#update_table as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pKvsDq8Lj5fI8Gw+Ia+LMnsKIM/fElmrCHsQHmmK6xnqZrLr3ei4gVhCipEEu9ntO3fFZ9ZwncLwx0X+dcnrjg==", "val"=>" tmp_kapow_test", "button"=>""}
  Rendering page/update_table.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered page/update_table.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2642ms (Views: 182.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the `HTML` generated from your view (i.e. the form-part of it) and the `params` hash shown in your console when you submit the form with some value selected?

Comment: Look in the rails console, to see the format of the params hash that is passed from the form and to ensure the value is being passed.

Comment: @SagarRS there seems to be `"val"=>" tmp_kapow_test"` in your `params`, so your `value` should not be empty (try printing it). However it looks like a *very* racy concept to use a user-changeable string to delete *some* table in your database completely. Keep in mind that hackers may manipulate their responses *in any way they which*. You should definitely sanitize the `value` before deleting the table. It is slightly strange that you have  a space at the beginning of your `value`, but this should not stop the `SQL` from executing.

Comment: @Patru Thank you very much am new to ROR and learning will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: For options_for_select, don't use `each` - I doubt that's your problem, though as the array returned from each will work there.  A suggestion - add the gem `better_errors` and raise an exception near your code - you can get better visibility into `params` and maybe see why the assignment is failing.

Comment: ok will try that @Swards

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed: depending on your version of `ruby`

```
params[:val]
```

will *not* be the same as

```
params['val']
```

Most likely to be the problem in this case.

Comment: @SagarRS the accepted way of saying "thank you" on StackOverflow is to accept an answer (if it works :-).

Comment: Really?  I thought params was a hash with indifferent access (string or symbol)  I can't find anything that says differently.

Comment: @Swards you might be correct, I only checked it with a `Hash`. Up to @SagarRS to decide if it works in rails.

Comment: With Rails 5, parameter hashes are no longer of type HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Comment: when i try to print params in logs "Rails.logger.debug params.inspect" its not showing up. is it not reaching controller action ?  @Patru

Comment: As Linus pointed out you should specify which version of rails you are using. Rails has been getting more and more cautious about which parameters it will actually allow to sift through (for excellent reasons, there have been attacks). So depending on the version you are using you might have to take different measures to let your params reach where you want them.

Comment: In rails 5.0, params is a ActionController::Parameters instance (no longer HashWithIndifferentAccess), but still allows params[:val] or params['val'] (string or symbol).